# Not able to know the reason of segmentation fault

Tags: c

I want make a tictactoe game program. It's unfinished yet but probably there are some problems that I can't figure out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

play(){
    char input[3][3],player1[100],player2[100];
    int i,j,k,times;
    for (j=0;j<3;j++){
        for (k=0;k<3;k++){
            input[j][k]='_';
        }
    }
    printf ("How many times do you want to play?\n");
    scanf ("%d",&times);
    printf ("Enter the name of first player : \n");
    scanf ("%s",player1);
    printf ("Enter the name of second player : \n");
    scanf ("%s",player2);
    printf ("Who will enter first letter?" "\n\n1. %s" "\n1. %s" "\n\nEnter 1 or 2 : \n",player1,player2);
    scanf ("%d",&i);
    for (j=0;j<times;j++){
        for (k=0;k<9;k++){
            if (i==1){
                if (k==0 || k%2==0){
                    printf("This is %s's chance.",player1);
                }
                if (k==1 || k%2==1){
                    printf("This is %s's chance.",player2);
                }
            }
            if (i==2){
                if (k==0 || k%2==0){
                    printf("This is %s's chance.",player2);
                }
                if (k==1 || k%2==1){
                    printf("This is %s's chance.",player1);
                }
            }
            printf ("%s   %s   %s\n\n%s   %s   %s\n\n%s   %s   %s\n\n",input[0][0],input[0][1],input[0][2],input[1][0],input[1][1],input[1][2],input[2][0],input[2][1],input[2][2]);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int i;
    printf("Welcome to TicTacToe made by Saurabh.\n\n1. Play\n2. Help\n\nEnter 1 or 2 : ");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    switch (i){
        case 1:
            play();
            break;
        case 2:

            break;
        default:
            printf ("Invalid response from user.");
    }
}
```

After running `scanf("%d",&i)` in the `play` function it says segmention fault but I can't figure out why that's happening. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your first loop you are only assigning `input[0][0]`.

Comment: In your "long" `printf` you are also printing `input[0][0]`  with a `%s` specifier. Please fix all of the compiler warnings first. I am sure you have some.

Comment: Oh I was just checking by just putting `input[0][0]` when I got fault.

Comment: `player1` is an array so it will decay to a pointer. You should use `scanf ("%s",player1);` (no `&`).

Comment: This seems like a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially how to run your program in a debugger to catch crashes as and when they happen, and be able to locate where in your code it happens.

Comment: I am using tcc and its not giving any kind of warning.

Comment: Do you compile with option "-Wall"?

Comment: @SergeBallesta its still giving segmentation fault.

Comment: The T in [`tcc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler) stands for *Tiny*. It's fast but most importantly *small*. That means it will have trade-offs, and once of them  is that it's lacking quite a lot of diagnostics that larger compilers would have.

Comment: Ok i will try it in gcc after some time until i will keep this on hold.

Comment: @Saurabh: the segmentation fault says that there is at least an error in the code. The shown code contains a number of errors.  It will only go away well all will be fixed... BTW I assume you also fixed the line for `player2`, didn't you.

Comment: Yeah i fixed that one too.

Comment: Btw if there are a lot of problems then anyone plz fix them. I am not able to find them. I will be very grateful to him.

Comment: Hey guys my Id is banned from asking questions so if u can upvote me that will be grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some prints I have seen there are some problems in this line:

```
printf ("%s   %s   %s\n\n%s   %s   %s\n\n%s   %s   %s\n\n",input[0][0],input[0][1],input[0][2],input[1][0],input[1][1],input[1][2],input[2][0],input[2][1],input[2][2]);
```

You defined `char input[3][3]` so `input[0][0]` is a single char (and the others with different indexes too) just like if I define `char my_str[10];`, `my_str[0]` is a single char.

I don't know if this is what you want but changing to:

```
printf ("%c   %c   %c\n\n%c   %c   %c\n\n%c   %c   %c\n\n",input[0][0],input[0][1],input[0][2],input[1][0],input[1][1],input[1][2],input[2][0],input[2][1],input[2][2]);
```

should not generate the error.

Comment: Thanks you very much.